# Android: How to pass data from service to broadcast reciever

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast

In my laboratory work I have to create a service, which sends notifications when speed of battery discharging is greater then set.

I created an Activity with EditText for this value and 2 button for starting and stopping the service. Also I created a BatteryService class, inherited form Service class and BatteryReciever.

Now reciver registers with action BATTERY_CHANGED in service in onStartCommand. And problem is how to pass data to reciever or how to know about events in service.

What is the best way to solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To trigger a `BroadcastReceiver`, you need to use

```
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Put the data you want to send from the `Service` in the `intent` as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.custom.action");
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("name", name);
b.putShort("count", count);
intent.putExtra("bundle", b);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And retrieve the data in the `onReceive()` method of the `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Override
public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    // do awesome things ...
}
```

Try this. This will work.

Comment: if I sendBroadcast, it will be call another instance of reciever. After invocation I will lose it

Comment: there is no "another instance of receiver". The `Intent` activates the currently registered receiver.

Comment: I get expected effect, but I created intent with my custom action (and reciever registered with it too). With explicit intent it was as I said. Thank you,  you were a great help to me

Comment: You're welcome, of course ... I've edited the answer to reflect your feedback.